# Find the number of divisors of $f'(1)$

Tags: number-theory, derivatives, polynomials

The question is that:

> Let $f(x) = x^{25} + 2x^{24} + 3x^{23} + 4x^{22} + \cdots + 25x$. Find the number of positive divisors of $f'(1)$.

How to find this number easily? Is there only one way: calculating one by one?

Comment: Let $P_i(x)=x^i+x^{i-1}+\cdots+x=\frac{x^i-x}{x-1}$ we have:
$$f(x)=P_{25}(x)+P_{24}(x)+\cdots+P_{1}(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}\left(P_{25}(x)-25x \right)=\frac{x^{25}-25x^2+24x}{(x-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
f'(1)&=\sum_{j=1}^{25}j(26-j)\\
&=2\cdot13^2\cdot 5^2-5^2\cdot13\cdot17\\
&=13\cdot5^2(26-17)\\
&=3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot13
\end{align}$$

So the number of divisors is $3\cdot 3\cdot 2=18$.

I have used these formulas:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n j=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^n j^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$

And the number of divisors of $p_1^{n_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_r^{n_r}$ is $(n_1+1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n_r+1)$

ADDED: Generalizing,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^{n}j(n+1-j)&=\frac16[3n(n+1)^2-n(n+1)(2n+1)]\\
&=\frac16n(n+1)(3n+3-2n-1)\\
&=\frac16n(n+1)(n+2)
\end{align}$$

Of course, the actual number of divisors will depend on how many of them has each factor.